# Use AJAX with form button to clear checkboxes in separate forms

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have a case where I need to have a Clear button on a form that not only clears out the form it's on, but also clears out checkboxes in other forms and clears data from ctools_object_cache.

The page is a custom search page created by the apachesolr module.  In the sidebar I have multiple blocks that are just 'checkboxes' form elements of taxonomy terms (each block is a separate vocabulary).  The checkboxes are used to select terms, which are written to ctools_object_cache using #ajax in the form when selected.  What I need is to have a Clear button (or link) on the search form that does a few things:

- Clears the search field
- Deletes items from ctools_object_cache
- Deselects the checkboxes in the sidebar forms
- Selects a specific checkbox in another sidebar block (labeled "All")

Is it possible to do this using a #ajax button with Forms API?  Or do I need to just write it as a separate Drupal behavior in jQuery?  I know Drupal forms can be handled in jQuery, but I haven't used it before, so I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In talking to Randy Fay, this will not work for a number of reasons, of which security is a big one.  Form API was written to avoid one form modifying other forms (among other things), so I re-architected the form elements to be all in one form instead of separate forms.